# How to convert multiple objects written in a file to an array of objects?

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, object

I have a file which has data stored in the following manner-

```json
{
name:Mike,
age:20
}
{
name:John,
age:19
}
```

I want to format this data and convert it into an array of objects so that the data appears in the following format-

```js
[
{
name:Mike,
age:20
},
{
name:John,
age:19
}
]
```

Is there any method to do this??

Comment: If the contents of the file are really as you've shown them, they aren't JSON, which requires `"` around property names.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that will do this entire process for you. You'll have to read the lines from the file, keep track of how many opening `{` you've seen, and when you've seen an equal number of `}`, capture the text from `{` to `}`, convert that to an object, and push it to an array. (Sadly, you can't use `JSON.parse` for that, because it requires that the input be valid JSON. If you trust that the file doesn't contain anything malicious, you could use `eval` for that. Just beware that `eval` allows arbitrary code execution, so you have trust the file contents.)

Comment: Yes I just meant that the file which I downloaded had a .json extension but I understand that it is not in a correct json format. I have edited my question for clarity.

Comment: As suggested above, you might want your input file to be a real JSON file (not only by file extension). Then you can easily use native node.js functions like `fs.readSync` to read it and JSON.parse to parse it into a variable. Any other walk around will be considered as a bad practice and a real nightmare.